# Is there way to write hdf5 files row by row in Python?

Tags: python, hdf5, pytables, hdfql

For CSV files we could use

```
writer = csv.writer(output)
writer.writerow([a, b, c, d])
```

Is there anything like that for writing Hdf5 files?

Comment: Yes, you can append to tables and earrays. Which Python HDF5 module are you using? `h5py` or `pytables (tables)`?

Comment: 'h5py or pytables (tables)' uh, I thought they were the same thing? The data I am using have two rows of string and two rows of float32. And I want this to be readable in Pandas. Is there any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to your other question.[Error when trying to save hdf5 row where one column is a string and the other is an array of floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55943319)

With pytables, you can create an empty table referencing a dtype that defines each datataype (in this example, 4 floats). Then you use `table_object.append(row_data)` to add 1 or more rows of data, where `row_data` can be defined with a list of tuples or a numpy recarray. See complete example I posted to answer question above.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not bound to a specific technology, check out [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com) as this will alleviate you from low-level details when dealing with HDF5 files.

To solve your question, you need to create a dataset with two dimensions: the first is extendible and the second has a size of four (based on your code snippet, I assume you want to store four integers per row; also, if the datatype is not an integer, please check HDFql [reference manual](http://www.hdfql.com/resources/HDFqlReferenceManual.pdf) for an enumeration of all datatypes and change the code snippet below accordingly).

In Python, to create such dataset execute (called `dset` in this example):

```
HDFql.execute("CREATE DATASET dset AS INT(UNLIMITED, 4)")
```

Then, for each row you want to write, execute (please replace `val0`, `val1`, `val2` and `val3` with proper values):

```
HDFql.execute("INSERT INTO dset[-1:::] VALUES(%d, %d, %d, %d)" % (val0, val1, val2, val3))
```

... finally, extend the first dimension of dataset `dset` by one like this:

```
HDFql.execute("ALTER DIMENSION dset TO +1")
```

Repeat code snippet line #2 and #3 as many times as the rows you want to write.